# How can I resolve an error where JSch fails public key authentication while other utilities are successful with the same key?

Tags: java, ssh, sftp, jsch

I've been using the Java JSch library to connect to SFTP sites to download files.  This has worked pretty flawlessly until recently.  Now a single SFTP site is failing public key authentication; the same key can be used to connect to the failing site using command-line sftp (solaris) and FileZilla (Windows).  I think I must have something configured incorrectly, and I was wondering if anybody could provide any solution to this problem.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

I'm using Java 1.8 and JSch v0.54.  Here's an example that fails.
package jsch_test;

```
import java.util.Properties;

import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;

public class Test {
    static {
        JSch.setLogger(new TestLogger());
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) throws JSchException {
        Test test = new Test();
        final String identityFile = "w:/path/to/my/id_rsa";

        // Known-good SFTP site
        //test.connect("test.known-good.site", "username", 22, identityFile);


        // Failing SFTP site
        test.connect("test.failing.site", "differentUsername", 6039, identityFile);
    }

    public void connect(String host, String user, int port, String identityFile) throws JSchException {
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        jsch.addIdentity(identityFile);

        Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);

        Properties config = new Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");

        session.setConfig(config);

        try {
            session.connect();
        } finally {
            session.disconnect();
        }

    }

    public static class TestLogger implements com.jcraft.jsch.Logger {
        static java.util.Hashtable<Integer, String> name=new java.util.Hashtable<>();
        static{
            name.put(new Integer(DEBUG), "DEBUG: ");
            name.put(new Integer(INFO), "INFO: ");
            name.put(new Integer(WARN), "WARN: ");
            name.put(new Integer(ERROR), "ERROR: ");
            name.put(new Integer(FATAL), "FATAL: ");
        }

        public boolean isEnabled(int level){
            return true;
        }

        public void log(int level, String message){
            System.err.print(name.get(new Integer(level)));
            System.err.println(message);
        }
    }
}
```

This is what gets logged.

```
INFO: Connecting to test.failing.site port 6039
INFO: Connection established
INFO: Remote version string: SSH-2.0-Maverick_SSHD
INFO: Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.54
INFO: CheckCiphers: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256
INFO: CheckKexes: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521
INFO: CheckSignatures: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
INFO: SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent
INFO: SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received
INFO: kex: server: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
INFO: kex: server: ssh-rsa
INFO: kex: server: aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc
INFO: kex: server: aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc
INFO: kex: server: hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96
INFO: kex: server: hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96
INFO: kex: server: none
INFO: kex: server: none
INFO: kex: server: 
INFO: kex: server: 
INFO: kex: client: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
INFO: kex: client: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
INFO: kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes192-ctr,aes192-cbc,aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc
INFO: kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes192-ctr,aes192-cbc,aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc
INFO: kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
INFO: kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
INFO: kex: client: none
INFO: kex: client: none
INFO: kex: client: 
INFO: kex: client: 
INFO: kex: server->client aes192-cbc hmac-sha1 none
INFO: kex: client->server aes192-cbc hmac-sha1 none
INFO: SSH_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<2048<2048) sent
INFO: expecting SSH_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
INFO: SSH_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
INFO: expecting SSH_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
INFO: ssh_rsa_verify: signature true
WARN: Permanently added 'test.failing.site' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
INFO: SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
INFO: SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS received
INFO: SSH_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
INFO: SSH_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
INFO: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
INFO: Next authentication method: publickey
INFO: Authentications that can continue: keyboard-interactive,password
INFO: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
INFO: Authentications that can continue: password
INFO: Next authentication method: password
INFO: Disconnecting from test.failing.site port 6039
Exception in thread "main" com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:519)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
    at jsch_test.Test.connect(Test.java:38)
    at jsch_test.Test.main(Test.java:23)
```

Here is the log file from command line sftp, from the same machine using the same id_rsa key.

```
sftp -v -oPort=6039 -oIdentityFile=./id_rsa testuser@test.failing.site
Connecting to test.failing.site...
Sun_SSH_1.1.8, SSH protocols 1.5/2.0, OpenSSL 0x100020bf
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Rhosts Authentication disabled, originating port will not be trusted.
debug1: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to test.failing.site [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] port 6039.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file p2idrsa type -1
debug1: Logging to host: test.failing.site
debug1: Local user: timrthy Remote user: testuser
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version Maverick_SSHD
debug1: no match: Maverick_SSHD
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-Sun_SSH_1.1.8
debug1: use_engine is 'yes'
debug1: pkcs11 engine initialized, now setting it as default for RSA, DSA, and symmetric ciphers
debug1: pkcs11 engine initialization complete
debug1: ssh_gssapi_init_ctx(8a218, test.failing.site, 0, 0, ffbff13c)
debug1: GSS-API error while calling GSS_Init_sec_context(): Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Server not found in Kerberos database

debug1: Skipping GSS-API mechanism kerberos_v5 (Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Server not found in Kerberos database
)
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes192-cbc hmac-sha1 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes192-cbc hmac-sha1 none
debug1: Peer sent proposed langtags, ctos:
debug1: Peer sent proposed langtags, stoc:
debug1: We proposed langtags, ctos: i-default
debug1: We proposed langtags, stoc: i-default
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 204/384
debug1: bits set: 1031/2048
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'test.failing.site' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /export/home/timrthy/.ssh/known_hosts:61
debug1: bits set: 1009/2048
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: newkeys: mode 1
debug1: set_newkeys: setting new keys for 'out' mode
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: newkeys: mode 0
debug1: set_newkeys: setting new keys for 'in' mode
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: done: ssh_kex2.
debug1: send SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: p2idrsa
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey)
debug1: fd 7 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH receive window size: 198720 B
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: send channel open 0
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: ssh_session2_setup: id 0
debug1: Sending subsystem: sftp
debug1: channel request 0: subsystem
debug1: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 34000
sftp>
```

External connections from every machine on my network look like they come from the same IP, but I went ahead and verified that command line sftp from my machine does work, while using Java + JSch does not.  Command line sftp to other sites (4 different sites currently) AND Java + JSch DOES work, so I'm running out of ideas.

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Please check the debug output of command-line sftp (solaris). Is it using the same ciphers? Could you add that output to the question?

Comment: Are you sunning any of those other SFTP/SSH clients on the same machine as your Java code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how helpful this answer will be anyone.  It turns out that it was a problem on the remote server end.  The tech folks on the server side let me know the problem was fixed; they did not indicate what changes they had to make on their end to resolve it.  From my end, the JSch logging looks the same, except that the public key authentication is successful.

Thanks a lot to all of you who looked at this.